# How do I display a UIPopoverView as a annotation to the map view? (iPad)

Tags: ios, ipad

On the maps app in the IPad when you tap a pin you get a normal annotation with an "i" instead of a disclosure indicator. A further tap on the "i" reveals a popover view controller like this.

[image: map popover example]

Is there a way to easily achieve this?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

First add an annotation to the map and in the `viewForAnnotation` method, set the `rightCalloutAccessoryView` to a button of type, say, UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure (I don't think the blue info button is available by default).

Pressing the button will call the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method.  In this method, deselect the annotation and show your popover.  For example:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    [mapView deselectAnnotation:view.annotation animated:YES];

    YourContentViewController *ycvc = [[YourContentViewController alloc] init...
    UIPopoverController *poc = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:ycvc];
    [ycvc release];

    //hold ref to popover in an ivar
    self.annotationPopoverController = poc;

    //size as needed
    poc.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 400);

    //show the popover next to the annotation view (pin)
    [poc presentPopoverFromRect:view.bounds inView:view 
        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

    [poc release];
}
```

YourContentViewController is a subclass of UIViewController which you can code like any other view controller.  The Maps app looks like it has UITableView in the content.

Comment: Great answer, really detailed.

Comment: In the Maps app there is an interesting animation in this scenario, the rather than the the smaller bubble being dismissed and the new popover presented, the small bubble actually expands to fit the popover view. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: @Chris Wagner: Don't know how Maps app does it but try initially displaying popover with small height and then, using timer or performSelector:withObject:afterDelay, manually animating popoverContentSize and re-presenting popover with updated rect (origin shifted up and height increased).  Another option might be to first display/animate regular custom UIView that expands from middle and then display final-size popover over that (and remove custom UIView below).  In the Maps app, callout also shifts left/right and this can be done by updating view.calloutOffset.

Comment: annotationPopoverController is an ivar/property in the MKMapView's delegate, as the comment indicates.

Comment: FYI: This solution is for iPad as iPhone idiom cannot call UIPopoverController.

Comment: I used this code with [poc presentPopoverFromRect:view.frame inView:view 
        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES]; but it didn't work? So why it works with Bounds and not frame?

Comment: @Jignesh: Because the FromRect parameter is relative to the inView parameter.  The value in view.frame is relative to _its_ superview while view.bounds is relative to itself.

Comment: Thanks!! Now I know difference between bounds and frame.

Comment: @Anna do you handle rotation? I'm dismissing and showing popover again on selected annotation, but position sometimes is wrong

Comment: I'm not able to show the popover from pinAnnotation's position, any solution!?
pleasse help.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that to have a better position for the popover you must present it from this rect:

```
CGPoint lc_point = [mapView convertCoordinate:view.annotation.coordinate toPointToView:mapView];
CGRect lc_frame = CGRectMake(lc_point.x,lc_point.y-view.frame.size.height,0,0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a library like Gordon Hughes' [Animated Callout](https://github.com/GiK/gik-animated-callout). Unfortunately it's still not working perfectly on iOS 6 (callouts show up strangely).

Here's iOS 5:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My requirement was similar to this issue, but also needed to allow users to interact with the map (panning and zooming) while the callout is displayed. 
For this I've created this github project: https://github.com/crarau/mapkit-custom-callout