# xcode map pins callouts

Tags: ios, mapkit

I'm trying to add callout to my pins . It ' s my first app with map callouts and i need help directing all the pins callouts to an external view .

```
-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    MKPinAnnotationView *MyPin=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"current"];
    MyPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;

    UIButton *advertButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [advertButton addTarget:self action:@selector(button:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    MyPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = advertButton;
    MyPin.draggable = NO;
    MyPin.highlighted = YES;
    MyPin.animatesDrop=TRUE;
    MyPin.canShowCallout = YES;

    return MyPin;
}
```

How can I add an external view when touching inside the blue arrow?

Comment: Have you written the `button:` method?  Do you have a view controller that you want to show?  Will the external view need to know which annotation was tapped?  What's the exact issue?

Comment: @Matteo What have you tried already? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've done this, but I think you need an NSObject for the map object.  I used [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial) tutorial when coding my last app using maps, and it helped a lot.  Possibly outdated, though.  Alternatively, you could build a custom map on the Google Maps website and parse the kml data, which inherently makes callout bubbles with the name, and from there you could code the callouts to be more complicated.  Yet another alternative is MapBox, a separate library which is easy and beautiful and has a lot of sample projects.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164469/ios-mapkit-custom-callout) is possibly a relevant SO question with code on making custom callout accessories.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your `- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation` method, try something along the lines of:

```
// Add button to callout
UIButton* advertButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = advertButton;
```

(In this example, `pinView` is the view you're returning from that method)

Then, add a method to the same class:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control {
    id <MKAnnotation> annotation = [view annotation];

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKPointAnnotation class]])
    {
        // TRANSITION TO VIEW HERE
    }
}
```

The class handling this should be a delegate of `MKMapViewDelegate`