# Popover on pin is not moving when map zooms

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview, apple-maps

Am showing a pop over view when clicks on pin(annotation), it is showing fine, after this when I zoom in or zoom out the map the pop over is not moving to according to the map zoom. So am getting the issue which is there in attached image.
How can I move the pop over according to respected pin on the map (when ever zooms the map)?

any suggestions is highly helpful.

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{

    NSString *strTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[view.annotation title]];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict;
    NSMutableArray *temp = annotationArray;
    for (int i = 0; i<[temp count]; i++)
    {
        dict = (NSMutableDictionary*)[temp objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *strAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"name"]];
        if([strAddress isEqualToString:strTitle]) {

            [mapView deselectAnnotation:view.annotation animated:YES];

            detailsViewController = [[PopOverViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PopOverViewController" bundle:nil];
//            [viewsPassage addObject:view];

//            NSOrderedSet *orderedSet = [[NSOrderedSet alloc] initWithArray:viewsPassage];
//            viewsPassage = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[orderedSet array]];
            if ([viewsPassage containsObject:view]) {
                NSLog(@"present");
                [self.poc dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
            }

            self.poc = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:detailsViewController];
            self.poc.contentViewController.view.alpha = 0;
            [viewsPassage addObject:userMapView];
            [self.poc setPassthroughViews:viewsPassage];
            [detailsViewController.textLabel setText:strAddress];
            //size as needed
            self.poc.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 400);
            //show the popover next to the annotation view (pin)
            CGRect popOverFrame = view.bounds;
            popOverFrame.size.width = 14;
            popOverFrame.size.height = 14;

            [self.poc presentPopoverFromRect:popOverFrame inView:view
               permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

[image: Issue am showing with arrow in the attached image.]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain the problem in decription

Comment: I have updated could u check it

Comment: Are you using Callouts of annotationView.?

Comment: `annotationView.canShowCallouts = YES` in viewForAnnotation?

Comment: Yes its already given, but no effects

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do or what the problem is.  However: a) Why are you holding reference to an MKPinAnnotationView (userMapView) in an ivar -- this doesn't look like a good idea.  b) `viewsPassage containsObject:view` doesn't look right -- `view` in this method is the _MKAnnotationView_ and later you do addObject with `userMapView` but don't you want to add the _MKMapView_ to the passthrough views instead of userMapView (which seems to be an MKPinAnnotationView)?

Comment: The picture doesn't explain anything.  Instead, edit your question and, in plain English, add a detailed description of your goal and what happens with the current code.  Please don't just say "it's not working" or "but no effects".  Explain exactly what is supposed to happen and what is happening instead of what you expected.

Comment: @Anna : I have updated could u please check it

Comment: Did you try with `[poc setPassthroughViews:@[[self view]]];` instead of the map view?

Comment: @Desdenova : No Luck Boss.. still the same

Comment: @iOSDev, thanks, the new picture now explains the problem.

Comment: @iOSDev, getting the callout to move smoothly with the annotation like it does in the Maps app requires that you either add the callout view to the annotation view itself or use a plain UIView instead of a UIPopoverController and move it in a pan gesture handler attached to the map.

Comment: @Anna : I have added the same code in - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control this method, yet i am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Like all views, your popover is located with respect to view coordinates, but you're expecting it to move as if it were located according to map coordinates. That won't happen automatically. Instead, you need to move the popover when the map region changes. There are methods in the map view delegate protocol that lets your map delegate take action when the region changes; take a look at [`-mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:).

As an alternative, consider that a popover might not be the right tool for the job, and a [custom callout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7164469/643383) might be a better solution.

Comment: Right.  However, the linked answer is basically what the OP is already doing.  For a "true" custom callout that automatically moves with the annotation, the callout view would have to be added to the annotation view itself instead (though this has its own issues).  It's better to just re-present the popover in the delegate method when the map is moved as you answered.

Comment: @Anna : Have u seen Apple Maps in iPad Simulator/device