# Show custom view after clicking on point Annotation iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to show some text after selecting point annotation on map. my text is large so I can not use `pointAnnot.title = @" string...";`

what is alternative for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this like describe [here](http://www.singsys.com/blog/use-mapkit-framework-to-create-a-custom-annotation-view-over-map-view/)

stack overflow questions

[one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582564/how-do-i-display-a-uipopoverview-as-a-annotation-to-the-map-view-ipad/5583505#5583505)

[two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164469/ios-mapkit-custom-callout)