# Annotation view similar to iPad Maps application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

In the maps application on the iPad, the annotation view's right callout accessory view looks like a detail disclosure button in the sense that it's blue with a white border, but instead of the right arrow, it has a lower-case 'i', similar to the info buttons. Assuming that this isn't custom, how do I create one?

Also, once that button is clicked, the annotation view is resized with an animation to include a table view underneath the title, and the view is moved to the left using an animation. Is this also a custom call, or is there a built-in API call for this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here's how to show the table + popover: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5583505/394504

And here's a cocoa control that does what I want: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/gikanimatedcallout

Comment: This control is broken on iOs6. You must use this delegate method `-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view` then get the right rect to display a popover: `CGPoint lc_point = [mapView convertCoordinate:view.annotation.coordinate toPointToView:mapView];
CGRect lc_frame = CGRectMake(lc_point.x,lc_point.y-view.frame.size.height,0,0);`