# MKAnnotationView frame not correct

Tags: ios, ipad, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotationview

I have method like this:

```
   - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIButton *)control
    {

            UIStoryboard *Mystoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
            CTObjectCreationVC *content = [Mystoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:TEST];
            content.modalInPopover = YES;

            content.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(500, 300);
            self.myPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:content];
            [self.myPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:control.bounds inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp | UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
    }
```

I need get frame `(MKAnnotationView *)view` for show my Popover. But I have very strange frame like this:

> MKPinAnnotationView: 0x1c600800; frame = (633571 327938; 32 39); tag =
>   3;

Why? Why X and Y very Big? How get real X and Y? Thanks

Log

> 2013-10-23 14:05:52.794 view frame:MKPinAnnotationView: 0x1f8c2160;
>   frame = (633548 328139; 32 39); tag = 17; gestureRecognizers =
>   NSArray: 0x1f8c2490>; layer = MKLayer: 0x1f8c21c0>> visible:1
>   +55.68109131, +37.51455307

Comment: have you try to print frame in `NSLog`? in this method.

Comment: I added log to my message

Comment: I'm not sure where and how you are logging this exactly but note that the presentPopoverFromRect can be done using the MKAnnotationView `view` parameter passed into the delegate method (instead of using `self.view` which is presumably the parent vc).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582564/how-do-i-display-a-uipopoverview-as-a-annotation-to-the-map-view-ipad/5583505#5583505 for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are getting this frame before the delegates are called,

Put `NSLog` in this method and check what is its frame.

```
   - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIButton *)control
    {
         NSLog("view frame:%@",view);
    }
```

Comment: I added log to my message