# Can not call annotationPopoverController

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, uipopovercontroller

I want to popover a view, but while coding I meet an error syntax and cannot find out the problem. My code base on the source [How do I display a UIPopoverView as a annotation to the map view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582564/how-do-i-display-a-uipopoverview-as-a-annotation-to-the-map-view-ipad/5583505#5583505)

and here the description of error by image:

[image]

**Edit**

The problem is **annotationPopoverController** just have on iPad. However, my project is for iPhone.

Comment: Have you created the property like explained in the other SO answer? annotationPopoverController looks like a custom property that they have set up. There is nothing about it in the docs.

Comment: Actually, this specific error has nothing to do with whether the project is for iPad or iPhone.  This error is just saying there is no property named "annotationPopoverController" in `self`.  This is not a default property (you have to create it).  Also, your error says "not found on object of type MKMapView *" which implies that `self` is a subclass of MKMapView.  I don't recommend that approach.  Instead, this code should be in a UIView or UIViewController subclass.  Still, if you want to use the `UIPopoverController` class at all, you'll need to run it on an iPad.

Comment: @Fogmeister : I read a commend into the link above my question: **annotationPopoverController is an ivar/property in the MKMapView's delegate, as the comment indicates. –  Paul Lynch** . It's not a custom property by myself.

Comment: @Anna: Yep, this code be in a UIView subclass. The 'edit' of my question is that I belief this property just have when I set my project for iPad target. And then I think, I need to resolve my problem by custom popover for iPhone.

Comment: @lee still, there is nothing in the docs. Only way that that property exists is if they created it themselves.